# how to sum values of duplicate element in array

Tags: c#

I have two arrays:

```
string[] fruit = { "apple", "banana", "lemon", "apple", "lemon" };
int[] quantity = { 2,          4,        1,      2,       2 };
```

The second one has the same length of the first one, and the integer numbers are the quantity of each fruit.

I want to create these two arrays:

```
totalefruit = { "apple", "banana", "lemon" };
totalquantity = {4,          4,       3}
```

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Care to show?

Comment: Why would you have 2 arrays to store these values? You should take a look at `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: You should look at creating an object or even a 2 dimensional array

Comment: I didn't know Dictionary<string, int>. I will take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: a 'lookup' would solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] fruit = { "apple", "banana", "lemon", "apple", "lemon" };
int[] quantity = { 2, 4, 1, 2, 2 };

var result =
    fruit
        .Zip(quantity, (f, q) => new { f, q })
        .GroupBy(x => x.f, x => x.q)
        .Select(x => new { Fruit = x.Key, Quantity = x.Sum() })
        .ToArray();

var totalefruit = result.Select(x => x.Fruit).ToArray();
var totalquantity = result.Select(x => x.Quantity).ToArray();
```

`result` looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: Yes! That's what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Zip` and a lookup:

```
var fruitQuantityLookup = fruit
    .Zip(quantity, (f, q) => new { Fruit = f, Quantity = q })
    .ToLookup(x => x.Fruit, x => x.Quantity);
string[] totalefruit = fruitQuantityLookup.Select(fq => fq.Key).ToArray();
int[] totalquantity = fruitQuantityLookup.Select(fq => fq.Sum()).ToArray();
```